# Null Forgiving Operator (!) on an Automatic Property

Tags: c#, null-forgiving-operator

I am trying to understand the Null Forgiving Operator.  I read the docs page on it and am left wondering if it can be used on properties.  Say I have the following class:

```
public class Note
{
    public long NoteId { get; set; }
    public string NoteText { get; set; }
    public long SectionId { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting a warning saying:

> CS8618: Non-nullable property 'NoteText' must contain a non-null value when exiting the constructor.  Consider declaring the property as nullable.

I don't want the property to be nullable.  But I also don't need a constructor.  This class is a Data Transfer Object (DTO) and is only ever passed in to my service or is constructed via AutoMapper.

I had hopped to use the Null Forgiving Operator here, but I can't seem to place it in a way that it will work.  (Oddly, Visual Studio will not even let me type it before or after the `NoteText` property name.)

My guess is that Null Forgiving is just not intended to be used like this.

But I thought I would ask, can the Null Forgiving Operator be used on Automatic Properties?

Comment: The requirement here seems contradictory. On the one hand "I don't want the property to be nullable" but then you are looking for a way to create a default Note instance having a null value for the string property.  I understand the intention is that the DTO object is probably filled up with valid data immediately, but still it seems like this leaves the 'contract' open to abuse or a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you're looking for is:

```
public string NoteText { get; set; } = null!;
```

> Oddly, Visual Studio will not even let me type it before or after the NoteText property name

That's correct, the `!` operator works on and in expressions, not identifier names.

Comment: Or set it to a non-null value, like an empty string. No ! needed then

Comment: Never set null parameters to an actual string value, it's lazy and makes checking against it more difficult for no reason. We're literally talking about nullable contexts and your "solution" is "don't use null, use a pretend value".

Comment: Then make them nullable, if null is a valid value

Comment: Same as above, you're in the wrong thread. We're talking about best practices here, not whatever it is you're talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing you could consider is to make the property `required` (feature added in C# 11).  Not a **direct** answer to the question about the null-forgiving operator, but it's what I've started doing in situations like this.

`CS8618` should go away in this file, since everyone who creates an instance of this class will have to give it a value (ignoring reflection), so the compiler doesn't have to worry about what it gets initialized to automatically.

Comment: Definitely what should be used if C# 11 is available.